# Git - I have deleted an entire folder by accident. How can I recover it?

Tags: git

I have deleted by accident the main project folder.

I have a local git repository and I've all commited. I'm trying to recover the folder but without success. I tested to do a git checkout to my last commit but the deleted folder have not come back.

Any clues on what I can do to recover this deleted folder?

Comment: Don't you have a remote repository to checkout from?

Comment: Please add more details. What are the folder paths? What are the exact commands that you used to delete your main project folder? What are the commands that you are using to try to recover it? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: When you say "main project folder", is this the folder that _contained_ your local git repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you have committed folder ever, please look in "git reflogs" and check out corresponding reflogs.

Folder will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If that folder has been version controlled(or, saved) by Git, this simple command will restore it:
`git reset --hard`

Since this command will restore everything since your last commit, you'd better backup your unsave files before issuing this command.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a third hint since your question is not very clear.

Did you remove the original repository folder, and want to restore it to make new clones?
If so...

Create a new empty repository.

`git init --bare 'new-path'`

Check the `origin` path of your local repository.

`git remote show origin`

If it is not correct, update the origin address.

`git remote set-url origin 'new-path'`

Later push your local repository to the new one with the `--mirror` argument

`git push --mirror origin`

Your local branches will not be pushed.